# Redirect output to 'file' command

Tags: file, unix-ar

Is there any way to have the `file` command get it's input from `stdin`? Specifically, I am trying to get the file type of a file in an archive, and am trying to do it in a single command. I tried this:

```
ar -p foo.a baz.o | file
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file -`.  The hyphen means "take input from standard input".

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

ar -p foo.a baz.o | xargs file

Comment: This is not a good idea; it will feed the output from `ar` (an object file) to `file` as a series of arguments.  This will not work well.